# How many scattering events happen in the atmosphere over 1 km?

Tags: atmospheric-science, radiative-transfer

In Vector Monte Carlo Atmospheric Radiative Transfer Simulations, they take a Stokes vector, let's say [1,1,0,0] and multiply it with a matrix, with elements close to 1. But if there are much scattering events, then the continuus multiplication with a number less then one should cause the Stokes vector to decrease to zero. Does it mean there are very few scattering events in the model, or matrix elements can take a greater value than 1? If they are greater then one, how is it that the Stokes-vector elements don't go over 1? How does it work?

Comment: Is the matrix you're referring a Müller matrix, and are the (norm of the) values <1 because you account for extinction? If I understand correctly, you're right that it means that too many scattering events make the Stokes' vector vanish, i.e. light is absorbed. But the abs. cross section is λ-dependent, and in the atmosphere there aren't many scattering events in the optical (or else it would be opaque), whereas there _are_ in, say, the UV (or else we would get sunburnt). The number of scatterings depend on λ, and can be calculated looking at a transmission curve of the atmosphere.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, sorry, I didn't clarify it, I was thinking in IR, somewhere about 800 nm-s.

Comment: It depends on the exact wavelength. In the [IR window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_window), the transmitted fraction of light goes from ~0% at 6-7 μm to 80-90% at both smaller and larger wavelengths. But I think the answer is given in [this earlier post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219986/70207).